# Excel VBA - How to extract numbers from String in each row of a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into an issue, I dont usually code in VBA so im having difficulties.
I'm trying to extract numbers from cells that contains a String(text).

The code that I currently have is working on a specific column, Column A in this case.

It loops over each row of that column.

It then puts the last number it found in the cell into the same row of column "B".

***For Example:***

**A2**: "123will", **B2**: 3.

**A3**: "12 Strawberries", **B3**: 2

---

What I am trying to get is the following(only the first 2 numbers):

***For Example :***

**A2** : "123will", **B2** : 12

**A3**: "12 Strawberries", **B3**: 12

**A4**: "15225 Street", **B4**: 15

**A5**: "Dog", **B5**: ""(empty)

What do I have to change in this code in order for it to work as I stated?

Thanks in advance! :)

```
Sub seperateNumbers()

    
    checkRange (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9999"))
   
End Sub

Private Sub checkRange(objRange As Range)

 Dim myAccessary As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
   
    iRow = 2
   
    For Each myAccessory In objRange        ' LOOP THROUGH ELEMENTS OR VALUES IN EACH ROW.
        For i = 1 To Len(myAccessory.Value) ' LOOP THROUGH EACH CHARACTER OF THE STRING (CELL VALUE).
            ' CHECK IF THE CHARACTER IS A NUMBER.
            If IsNumeric(Mid(myAccessory.Value, i, 2)) Then
               
                ' SHOW THE NUMBER IN THE 2ND COLUMN OF THE SAME ROW.
                If Trim(objRange.Cells(objRange.Row - 1, 2)) <> "" Then
                    objRange.Cells(iRow - 1, 2) = objRange.Cells(iRow - 1, 2) & Mid(myAccessory.Text, i, 2)
                Else
                    objRange.Cells(iRow - 1, 2) = Mid(myAccessory.Text, i, 2)
                End If
                    
            End If
        Next i
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next myAccessory
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions: Are all numbers always at the start of strings? Are all numbers 2 or more digits?

Comment: All numbers are at the start of the string, but they can be between 1 and 10 digits.

Comment: Try a formula like `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,2)*1,IFERROR(LEFT(A2,1)*1,""))` in **B2**

Comment: I want it to work on every workbook with a simple click.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp in UDF:

```
Function ExtractNumber(str As String) As String
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Dim res As IMatchCollection2, m As IMatch2
    Static re As RegExp
    If re Is Nothing Then
        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Global = False
        re.PATTERN = "\d+"
    End If
    
    Set res = re.Execute(str)
    If res.Count > 0 Then ExtractNumber = res(0)
End Function
```

**Note.** If the numbers are always at the beginning, you can use `n = Val(str)`

[image]

Comment: Can i use a function in multiple workbooks without adding the code each time?

Comment: Place the code into the PERSONAL.XLSB common module

Comment: Just to make it more clear, its a report excel file that I get everyday and I need to basically do the same thing each time. I want to be able to reuse the function without applying the code each time to the new excel file

Comment: I tried putting it in PERSONAL.XLSB but when i type in column B to search for the formula it doesnt show

Comment: Press `Shift+F3` and select from UDF section or type `=PERSONAL.XLSB!ExtractNumber(...)`

Comment: Nice. Note that `Val()` on a string that won't start with a digit would return 0.

Comment: Is there any way to reach this function without typing =PERSONAL.XLSB!ExtractNumber(...)?
it doesnt auto complete T-T

Comment: Yes. Make an addin `*.xlam`, turn it on and the public UDF inside will be available on the open book worksheets without the book name prefix.

Comment: I found it working quite well, thanks alot! :)
But I ran into another problem, after I open a new workbook, it doesnt save the reference to the VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5, I have to manually add it each time. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: You can use late binding - `Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")` instead of `Set re = New RegExp` and `Static re As Object` instead of `Static re As RegExp`. Also `Dim res As IMatchCollection2, m As IMatch2` will be `as Object`

Comment: wow, thanks alot! works perfectly now. I wish i could upvote but my account doesnt have the required reputation :(

Comment: I checked the code today at work, would love if any of you can help me adjust the code a little bit, 
The number is supposed to be at the beginning, meaning if at any point it reaches a non-integer character, it should return "", 
for example : wood 15 or wood15 should return ""(empty).
at the moment wood 15 or wood15 return 15.
what to change in the code in order for it to work like that?

Comment: re.PATTERN = "^\d{2}"

Comment: oh I was actually able to find that out thanks to regex101 website but thanks :)
is there any way to output "1" instead of "" in the cases I said?

Comment: nvm found that out also! :D thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a simple formula instead of overcomplicating things with VBA; here is a thought:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IFERROR(-LOOKUP(1,-LEFT(A1,ROW($1:$2))),"")
```

Comment: I responded to the others as well, I want to be able to use this code in every excel file.
In this case, I get a new excel file each day and I want to be able to just use this code instead of copy pasting the formula each time.

Comment: Then the other answers give directions on both using a single formula for a whole range *or* creating your own UDF-function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
Sub seperateNumbers()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B2", "B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            .Formula2 = "=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,2)*1,IFERROR(LEFT(A2,1)*1,""""))"
            .Value2 = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this but it didnt do anything, no errors too

Comment: This should work on `ThisWorkbook` in a sheet named `Sheet1`. Change as necessary

Comment: Still not working unfortunately, is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it is working for me. I am using Microsoft 365. What version are you using? Try changing `.Formula2` to `.Formula` and `.Value2` to `.Value`. (i.e. remove the `2`s)

Comment: I am also using Microsoft 365, tried removing the 2s but still not working.
But I also need it to work on Excel 2016 if possible(thats what I use at work)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot think of any reason why it doesn't work for you.